# laravel 5.5 HTTP ERROR 500 unable to handle this request

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

My old Project use Laravel 5.4.17 It can work in server normally.But new Project use Laravel 5.5.4 It can't work when route in root/public " mydomain.com/root/public is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500". Is it a problem with the version of php? Because current php version is 5.6.23. Laravel 5.5 require php 7.0? Do you think I'm right?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/upgrade . It's the first thing it says

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For Laravel 5.5 you need following server requirement

The Laravel framework has a few system requirements. Of course, all of these requirements are satisfied by the Laravel Homestead virtual machine, so it's highly recommended that you use Homestead as your local Laravel development environment.

However, if you are not using Homestead, you will need to make sure your server meets the following requirements:

```
PHP >= 7.0.0
OpenSSL PHP Extension
PDO PHP Extension
Mbstring PHP Extension
Tokenizer PHP Extension
XML PHP Extension
```

Ref:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5#server-requirements

Comment: Ok I need to upgrade my server Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 9):

I hope, You already do this.

- You should change those public facing permissions to 644.
- Change the **Storage** folder permission to 777.
- Check the logs.
- Make sure you configured nginx properly and then restart nginx.
- Should you be sure the APP_KEY is in the .env file.
- You should run `php artisan config:clear` after any changes to .env.

Comment: Don't forget to run `composer install` when there are new or updated packages.

Comment: Important to remember: I used to give folder permissions to:
      >> sudo chmod -R ug+rwx storage bootstrap/cache
      >> sudo chmod -R 777 storage
      >> sudo chmod -R 777 bootstrap/cache

Comment: Change the Storage folder permission to 777.
my problem fixed after change permission storgae folder to 775 thank you

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue on Laravel 8, turns out the problem arose from interrupting a `composer update` process.

If you are in the same situation, just run `composer update`, that should fix it.

Answer (score 2):

I faced this problem too many times, the solution was to run **#composer install and/or #composer update** to update the composer dependencies packages, or you might even lost the .htaccess file during moving/copying the files in the live server

Answer (score 1):

For Laravel 8 in docker, you might want to change the permission of your storage folder.

```
sudo chmod -R 777 storage
```

Answer (score 1):

Add these two lines to your index.php file to see the error.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I use Manjaro Linux. I installed Apache, MySQL, Php, PhpMyAdmin separately (not using lampp)

this issue "**localhost is currently unable to handle this request**" appears because we have to enable display_error in the php configuration located at

> `/etc/php/php.ini`

switch display error to on

```
display_errors = On
```

and

```
display_startup_errors = On
```

then restart apache server

```
sudo systemctl server restarting httpd
```

then information about the error will appear in your browser

Answer (score 0):

in my case i changed hosting companies and i had to move my files to the new host. in the new host my php version was around 8.* and in the previous host it was around 7.*, i searched and did EVERYTHING! i then had a thought and reduce the version and boom that was it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).